# iOS 7: UINavigationController pulls down UIScrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a full screen UIScrollView, in which I place my UIImageView (subview). But when I connect this Controller with my UINavigationController, the image in it gets pulled down (the same height as the bar).

Tried the following:

> self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

Also tried to reset frame position or offset. Nothing helps.

Comment: Are you using xib or storyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```